# Make Facebook use 24h format instead of AM/PM

Tags: facebook, localization

Facebook always shows me hours as AM and PM ([12-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock)).

When creating Facebook events it is cumbersome, and on several occasions I have scheduled a lunch for 12AM.

How to make Facebook use the [24 hours format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock), while still keeping the interface in English?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution is to change Facebook's language to [British English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_English):

`Settings` > `Language` > `Which language do you want to use Facebook in?`

[image: Facebook set British English]

Select `English (UK)` and now you can now create events using the 24 hours format:

[image: Facebook event 24 hours]

Comment: for me - it needed change to "English" and then back to what I had already set - to switch from 12h to 24h format

Answer (score 1):

Go the your [Facebook settings](https://web.facebook.com/settings?tab=language&section=region&view) on the `Language and Region` tab and set the `Formats for dates, times and numbers` under `Region format` to something appropriate, like `South Africa (English)`

[image: Screenshot of the relevant setting, which is directly linked anyway]

Comment: @marikamistos: I have avoided the code quotes since they were converted to normal quotes on other sites...

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it after weeks of being annoyed. If you have an iPhone go to settings, then general then language and region then change the iPhone language I set mine to English (Canada) and it went back to the 12 hour time. I’m so happy!!